# Passing Control in C

Tags: c

In object-oriented programming, I know you can pass control between classes, which makes things much more organized. I realize that there aren't classes in C because it isn't an object-oriented programming language, but is there a way that I can write a new file, that I can pass control to? Just to make things easier?

What I'm really asking is : how do I pass control to an outside extension of the program, and do I need to use any special type of program (.dll, etc.)

Comment: Are you talking about libraries? Then you can use `-l` flag with GCC

Comment: Control of what? Keyboard, mouse, event handling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, C++ does not introduce much in the sence of program structure organization when compared to C.

You don't really pass controll *between classes* in C++. You just call methods of classes. Class methods are just functions with several additional capabilities. Thus you can use the same tactics of *passing control* in C as you do in C++. For example:

```
//C++
class A {
public:
A(int n) { /*...*/ }
int DoSomething() { /*...*/ }
protected:
int m_SomeMember;
double m_AnotherMember;
};

AInst(8);
int x = AInst.DoSomething();

//C
struct A {
int m_SomeMember;
double m_AnotherMember;
};

void InitializeA(struct A* pa, int n)
{ 
/*...*/ 
}

int DoSomethingWithA(struct A* pa)
{
/*...*/ 
}

struct A AStructInst;
InitializeA(&AStructInst, 8);
int y = DoSomethingWithA(&AStructInst);
```

The only problem, you may need more effort to structurize your program in C when compared to C++. For example, the latter language will take care about proper initialization and destruction of objects, while in C you have to take care of such stuff yourself.

As for using static and/or dynamic libraries, the 2 languages are mostly identical. You will have more trouble when trying to make C++ libraries portable to other compiler and/or platform though due to many subtle differences like function names mangling, vtables and stuff like that.

Comment: Exactly what I was asking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In C, you "pass control" between functions.  In C++, you "pass control" between either classes or functions.

Other than that, there's very little difference: the behavior of a program written in one language is virtually indistinguishable from the runtime bheavior of a similar program written in the other language.

Perhaps you're thinking of "shared libraries"?  Shared libraries depend on the platform (e.g. Windows vs. Linux), and not so much on the programming language (C vs C++).

Or perhaps you're thinking of "runtime loadable classes" (like Java or C#).  These depend on the "virtual machine" (e.g. the Java JRE or .Net runtime).  Neither C nor C++ run inside such a VM, and neither support "runtime loadable classes" beyond the capabilities offered by shared libraries (and, again: shared libraries work equally well with either C or C++).

'Hope that helps...